# Grouping of messages with more than one max value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a private messaging system within a forum. I want to rebuild this messaging system so that it is no longer messaged based but instead it should be conversation based. It should be like Whatsapp or any other messenger where you have no messages but contacts.

I have have written the following SQL query.

```
    SELECT t.*, 
       p.root_level, 
       p.message_time, 
       p.icon_id, 
       p.to_address, 
       p.message_attachment, 
       p.bcc_address, 
       u.username, 
       u.username_clean, 
       u.user_colour, 
       p.message_reported, 
       Max(p.msg_id) AS maxid, 
       p.message_subject 
FROM   phpbb3_privmsgs_to t 
       LEFT JOIN phpbb3_privmsgs p 
              ON ( p.msg_id = t.msg_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN phpbb3_users u 
              ON ( u.user_id = p.author_id ) 
WHERE  t.user_id = 1234 
       AND t.user_id != p.author_id 
       AND t.pm_deleted = 0 
GROUP  BY t.author_id, 
          t.user_id 
ORDER  BY maxid DESC
```

This query is working well. The grouping works and the sorting but the message_time in each group is not the latest. The time / date of the oldest conversation is taken.

How is it possible to get the latest message_time in every group?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The original query was a bit longer and I made the query smaller because I dont want to make it more complicated as necessary. I will update my question after I have tested the soluation from O. Jones.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updatet my Query. It should be valid now, thank you.

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Come. Join us. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your query misuses [MySQL's notorious non-standard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). The way your GROUP BY query is written, MySQL returns an unpredictable row, not the latest row, from your `privmsgs`  table.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the very common "get the details for the row with the max value" requirement. In your case you want to fetch, for each author, the most recent message in your `privmsgs` table.  Then you want to JOIN that to your `users` table.

First, use a subquery to find the most recent message time for each author (user). Like this:

```
                SELECT author_id,  MAX(message_time) message_time
                  FROM privmsgs
                 GROUP BY author_id
```

Test this by hand. Notice that it gives exactly one row for each `author_id` value, with a column showing the most recent `message_time`. You need that `message_time` to choose which row you'll need to  get the details from.

Let's do that. Next, incorporate that subquery into your query, something like this.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, 
       p.*, whatever, but no MAX() functions
  FROM users u
  JOIN privmsgs p ON u.user_id = p.author_id
  JOIN (
                SELECT author_id,  MAX(message_time) message_time
                  FROM privmsgs
                 GROUP BY author_id
       ) maxmsgt    ON p.author_id = maxmsgt.author_id
             AND p.message_time = maxmsgt.message_time

 WHERE (whatever filter)
 ORDER BY (whatever order)
```

JOINing that subquery lets you give an ON condition to get only the messages with the latest time. Your GROUP BY operation is in the subquery, not the main query. It looks complicated, but it's a very common query pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much @O. Jones for getting into my problem. Untested, the description "get the details for the row with the max value" sounds very well to me. I will test your solution in the next mins.

Comment: It looks indeed very complicated. I have updated my question. The original query was a bit longer and I made the query smaller because I dont want to make it more complicated as necessary. Now Its the right one. I tried to adapt your query to mine but I dont get it. Would you please update your answer with accordingly to my question? Thank you very much for your time. Also, is that x in x.author_id correct?

Comment: would you please have a look again? Thank you very much.

Comment: The `x` in the query was an alias for the  subquery. Notice that subqueries and tables are interchangeable in FROM / JOIN clauses. I changed the alias to `maxmsgt` to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I appreciate it. This make the query clearer to me. The problem I had in the last hours is, that I dont know how to combine your solution into my updated query I made after you provided me your solution. Would you please have a look at my query in the first post and add into this one the subquery? Please notice that there is added a another table with the name privmsgs_to. Thank you very much for your precious time.